# How can I ensure thread safe when using sequence in Database?

Tags: stored-procedures, informix

I have a sequence used in a stored proc that update multiple table just like below:

```
create procedure()
   -- retrieve new sequence number
   sequence.nextval();

   -- update table_A using newly created sequence number
   insert into table_A(theID) values(sequence.currval());

   -- update table_B using newly created sequence number
   insert into table_B(theID) values(sequence.currval());
end procedure;
```

May I know whether the code above is a thread-safe implementation? For each procedure's execution, can I guarantee theID in table_A and table_B always retrieving the same sequence number when there are more than one execution at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of Informix's primary objectives is to make sure that procedure works exactly as you need it to, regardless of how many thousands of users are also running the same procedure at the same time.  Indeed, you can have multiple concurrent sessions of your own each running the procedure and each session is isolated from all the other sessions.

So, the code shown is 'thread safe'.

Comment: Thank you so much on your reply, may I know is this apply to trigger as well? If this is true, then I could save a lot of efforts. ;)

Comment: Yes, the same applies inside a trigger.